# Finding constants so that matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I'm teaching myself linear algebra and came upon this exercise. It is probably not very hard, but I just have hard time solving it.

$$\text{Which values for constants a, b, c, d, e, f make the matrix diagonalizable?}\\
A= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & b & c \\
        0 & 2 & d & e \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & f \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I have tried wrestling this for many hours now and I need some help. What I have been able to do so far, that I know of is correct:

The characteristic polynomial is $$p(\lambda)=(\lambda-2)^3(\lambda-1)$$ and therefore the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for those are $$\lambda_1=2,\space \lambda_2=1$$

Also the two eigenvectors are
$$v_1=[1,0,0,0]^T \text{ and } v_2=[a,1,0,0]^T$$

That is what I have for certain.

--

Then there are some other things I've been thinking, but which I'm not sure of:

I assume that in $$D=P^{-1}AP$$ the D would be
$$ D= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

as the eigenvalues should be on the diagonal and the eigenvalue 2 is repeated.

One great point of uncertainty is that I seem to be missing $2$ vectors from the $P$ (so that it would be $4\times 4$ matrix) and I don't seem to find a way to constructing them. I know that the 2 missing vectors should be linearly independent, but only vectors I could think of were vectors $[0,0,1,0]^T$ and $[0,0,0,1]^T$ and that lead to following when $D=P^{-1}AP$ is used:

$$ 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
=  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}   
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & b & c \\
        0 & 2 & d & e \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & f \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
=  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2a & b & c \\
        -a & 2-2a^2 & d-ab & e-ac \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & f \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

And if that is correct, all constants have to be $0$, otherwise it is not diagonalizable. But I'm very skeptical that this would be the correct answer. I think I need somehow link the additional two eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $2$, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm very grateful for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda=2$,     $(A-2I)v=0$ gives the augmented matrix for the homogeneous system as

$\begin{pmatrix}-1&a&b&c:0\\0&0&d&e:0\\0&0&0&f:0\\0&0&0&0:0\\\end{pmatrix}$

What you really need that is $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors from this i.e. $n-r=3$ where $n$($=4$ here) is number of variables and $r$ is rank of the above matrix. Can you see that only $d=e=f=0$ is sufficient for $r=1$.

Comment: is the solution then $d=e=f=0$, and $a=b=c$ can be freely chosen? And then the eigenvectors would be $v_1=[1,0,0,0]$, $v_2=[a,1,0,0]$, $v_3=[b,0,1,0]$ and $v_4=[c,0,0,1]$,

Comment: @juahan......yes.

Comment: Oh man, turned out to be much easier than I thought. Again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You only have two eigenvalues: $\;\lambda=1\;,\;\;\lambda=2\;$ , the first one with algebraic multiplicity equto to one (and thus *also* geometric mult. one), and the other one with alg. mult. three, and **you need** need also its geom. mult. to be three, too. So let us check the homogeneous linear system to ge the eigenspace for $\;\lambda=2\;$ and try to check whether it ispossible to get one with solution space of dimension three:

$$\begin{cases}&x-&ay-&bz-&\;\;\;cw=0\\
&&&-dz-&\;\;\;ew=0\\
&&&&-fw=0\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies$$

if $\;f\neq0\;$ then $\;w=0\;$ , but then the first equation is just a two dimensional plane, so we need $\;w\neq0\implies f=0\;$ . Take it from here now.